# Angular-Service Array.filter vs basic for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I'm modifying an array inside a service, while having bound to the service properties inside a directive. Now I want to remove one item from the array, but I couldn't get `Array.filter` to work. I am not sure if it is because `Array.filter` is **asynchron** or because it returns a **new array** instead of modifying the original or the **$digest** cycle. A common for loop does work, but since I read about the advantages of the more declarative array methods I thought I would ask you why it doesn't work.

**Directive**

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  function MyDirective(MyService) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "template.html",
      scope: {
        limit: "="
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.array= MyService.array;

        scope.removeItem = function (index) {
          MyService.removeItem(index);
        };
      }
    };
  }

  angular
    .module("Module", [])
    .directive("myDirective", ['MyService', MyDirective]);

}());
```

**Service with Array.filter**

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  function MyService() {
    var array = [];

    function removeItem(idx) {
      array = array.filter(function(item) {
        return item.index !== idx;
      });
    }

    return {
      array: array,
      removeItem: removeItem
    };
  }

  angular
    .module("Module")
    .factory("MyService", [MyService]);

}());
```

**Service with for loop**

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  function MyService() {
    var array = [];

    function removeItem(idx) {
      for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].index === idx) {
          array.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      array: array,
      removeItem: removeItem
    };
  }

  angular
    .module("Module")
    .factory("MyService", [MyService]);

}());
```

thanks

**Edit:** To clarify what I mean with "It doesn't work", the UI doesn't get updated and when I output the length of the array before and after the Array.filter, it is still the same size. I also checked the next time I delete an item, it is still the same as the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you re-assign a variable, references to the variable do not automatically update to reference the new variable.

Comment: That makes sense, would it be the correct way to return the new array and rebind it in the directive? Or is there an angular way to doing that? thanks

Comment: The best solution would depend on what other things the service will need to do. This is one of the few cases where using a ```service``` instead of a ```factory``` would be useful. You could also create an object which stores the array and return that object. You can create a function which retrieves the array (a getter). Or, just use your array-modifying approach.

Answer (score 0):

When you inject the service, it returns the object you return from your service function, which has two properties, an empty `array` array and a function named `removeItem`.  When you call `removeItem`, it sets the value of the `array` var in your function scope, but it does not alter the value on your returned object.  Try this:

```
function MyService() {
  var obj = {
    array: [],
    removeItem: function removeItem(idx) {
      obj.array = obj.array.filter(function(item) {
        return item.index !== idx;
      });    
    }
  };

  return obj;
}
```